# SQL - '1' IF hour in month EXISTS, '0' IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has aggregations down to the hour level `YYYYMMDDHH`.  The data is aggregated and loaded by an external process (I don't have control over).  I want to test the data on a monthly basis.

The question I am looking to answer is:  Does every hour in the month exist?

I'm looking to produce output that will return a `1` if the hour exists or `0` if the hour does not exist.

The aggregation table looks something like this...

```
YYYYMM  YYYYMMDD    YYYYMMDDHH  DATA_AGG
201911  20191101    2019110100  100
201911  20191101    2019110101  125
201911  20191101    2019110103  135
201911  20191101    2019110105  95
…   …   …   …
201911  20191130    2019113020  100
201911  20191130    2019113021  110
201911  20191130    2019113022  125
201911  20191130    2019113023  135
```

And defined as...

```
CREATE TABLE YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG AS (
    YYYYMM      VARCHAR,
    YYYYMMDD    VARCHAR,
    YYYYMMDDHH  VARCHAR,
    DATA_AGG    INT
);
```

I'm looking to produce the following below...

```
YYYYMMDDHH     HOUR_EXISTS
2019110100     1
2019110101     1
2019110102     0
2019110103     1
2019110104     0
2019110105     1
...            ...
```

In the example above, two hours do not exist, `2019110102` and `2019110104`.

I assume I'd have to join the aggregation table against a computed table that contains all the `YYYYMMDDHH` combos???

The database is Snowflake, but assume most generic ANSI SQL queries will work.

Comment: *two hours do not exist* where?

Comment: @forpas I added some additional info.  In the actual table, hours `2019110102` and `2019110104` do not exist.

Comment: What is the data type of the column `YYYYMMDDHH`?

Comment: @forpas VARCHAR

Comment: In your expected results the 1st column represents dates and not months. Do you want the column HOUR_EXISTS for each day or for each month?

Comment: @forpas I may have edited and added this after you asked the question above, but I am looking to answer this question, "Does every hour in the month exist?"  So, for November there are 720 hours, thus, I'd be looking to solve for each hour permutation (YYYYMMDDHH).

Comment: Fine, this is what your expected output looks like.

Comment: Since none of the answers are ANSI SQL compliant, I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want with a recursive CTE

The recursive CTE generates the list of possible Hours. And then a simple left outer join gets you the flag for if you have any records that match that hour.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (YYYYMMDDHH) as
(
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH
FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG
WHERE YYYYMMDDHH = (SELECT MIN(YYYYMMDDHH) FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG)

UNION ALL 

SELECT TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(HOUR, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP(C.YYYYMMDDHH, 'YYYYMMDDHH')), 'YYYYMMDDHH') YYYYMMDDHH
FROM CTE C
WHERE  TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(HOUR, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP(C.YYYYMMDDHH, 'YYYYMMDDHH')), 'YYYYMMDDHH') <= (SELECT MAX(YYYYMMDDHH) FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG)
)

SELECT 
    C.YYYYMMDDHH,
    IFF(A.YYYYMMDDHH IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) HOUR_EXISTS
FROM CTE C
LEFT OUTER JOIN YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG A
    ON C.YYYYMMDDHH = A.YYYYMMDDHH;
```

If your timerange is too long you'll have issues with the cte recursing too much. You can create a table or temp table with all of the possible hours instead. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE HOURS (YYYYMMDDHH VARCHAR) AS
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(HOUR, SEQ4(), TO_TIMESTAMP((SELECT MIN(YYYYMMDDHH) FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG), 'YYYYMMDDHH')), 'YYYYMMDDHH')
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 10000)) V 
  ORDER BY 1;

SELECT 
    H.YYYYMMDDHH,
    IFF(A.YYYYMMDDHH IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) HOUR_EXISTS
FROM HOURS H
LEFT OUTER JOIN YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG A
    ON H.YYYYMMDDHH = A.YYYYMMDDHH
WHERE H.YYYYMMDDHH <= (SELECT MAX(YYYYMMDDHH) FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG);
```

You can then fiddle with the generator count to make sure you have enough hours.

Comment: I ended up creating the hours table, albeit differently but same result on the hours table and desired outcome on the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a table with every hour of the month and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` your aggregation to it:

```
WITH EVERY_HOUR AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATEADD(HOUR, HH, TO_DATE(YYYYMM::TEXT, 'YYYYMM')),
                 'YYYYMMDDHH')::NUMBER YYYYMMDDHH
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YYYYMM FROM YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG) t
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) - 1 HH
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 745))
  ) h
  QUALIFY YYYYMMDDHH < (YYYYMM + 1) * 10000
)
SELECT h.YYYYMMDDHH, NVL2(a.YYYYMM, 1, 0) HOUR_EXISTS
FROM EVERY_HOUR h
LEFT OUTER JOIN YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG a ON a.YYYYMMDDHH = h.YYYYMMDDHH
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help get you started.  I'm guessing you want to have 'synthetic' [YYYYMMDD] values?  Otherwise, if the value aren't there, then they shouldn't appear in the list

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #_hours
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #_temp

```
--Populate a table with hours ranging from 00 to 23
CREATE TABLE #_hours ([hour_value] VARCHAR(2))
DECLARE @_i INT = 0
WHILE (@_i < 24)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #_hours
        SELECT FORMAT(@_i, '0#')
        SET @_i += 1
    END

-- Replicate OP's sample data set
CREATE TABLE #_temp (
    [YYYYMM] INTEGER
    ,   [YYYYMMDD] INTEGER
    ,   [YYYYMMDDHH] INTEGER
    ,   [DATA_AGG] INTEGER
)
INSERT INTO #_temp
VALUES 
(201911, 20191101, 2019110100, 100),
(201911, 20191101, 2019110101, 125),
(201911, 20191101, 2019110103, 135),
(201911, 20191101, 2019110105, 95),
(201911, 20191130, 2019113020, 100),
(201911, 20191130, 2019113021, 110),
(201911, 20191130, 2019113022, 125),
(201911, 20191130, 2019113023, 135)



SELECT X.YYYYMM, X.YYYYMMDD, X.YYYYMMDDHH
    -- Case: If 'target_hours' doesn't exist, then 0, else 1
,   CASE WHEN X.target_hours IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS [HOUR_EXISTS]
FROM (
    -- Select right 2 characters from converted [YYYYMMDDHH] to act as 'target values'
    SELECT T.*
    ,   RIGHT(CAST(T.[YYYYMMDDHH] AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) AS [target_hours]
    FROM #_temp AS T
) AS X
-- Right join to keep all of our hours and only the target hours that match.
RIGHT JOIN #_hours AS H ON H.hour_value = X.target_hours
```

Sample output:

```
YYYYMM  YYYYMMDD    YYYYMMDDHH  HOUR_EXISTS
201911  20191101    2019110100  1
201911  20191101    2019110101  1
NULL    NULL        NULL        0
201911  20191101    2019110103  1
NULL    NULL        NULL        0
201911  20191101    2019110105  1
NULL    NULL        NULL        0
```

Answer (score 0):

With (almost) standard sql, you can do a cross join of the distinct values of `YYYYMMDD` to a list of all possible hours and then left join to the table:

```
select concat(d.YYYYMMDD, h.hour) as YYYYMMDDHH,
  case when t.YYYYMMDDHH is null then 0 else 1 end as hour_exists
from (select distinct YYYYMMDD from tablename) as d
cross join (
  select '00' as hour union all select '01' union all
  select '02' union all select '03' union all     
  select '04' union all select '05' union all
  select '06' union all select '07' union all
  select '08' union all select '09' union all
  select '10' union all select '11' union all
  select '12' union all select '13' union all
  select '14' union all select '15' union all
  select '16' union all select '17' union all
  select '18' union all select '19' union all
  select '20' union all select '21' union all
  select '22' union all select '23'
) as h 
left join tablename as t
on concat(d.YYYYMMDD, h.hour) = t.YYYYMMDDHH
order by concat(d.YYYYMMDD, h.hour)
```

Maybe in Snowflake you can construct the list of hours with a sequence much easier instead of all those `UNION ALL`s.

Comment: Technically speaking, this behaves oddly if you have an entire day where there are now records since it does rely on records in the table to provide the relevant days

Answer (score 0):

This version accounts for the full range of days, across months and years.  It's a simple cross join of the set of possible days with the set of possible hours of the day -- left joined to actual dates.

```
set first = (select min(yyyymmdd::number) from YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG);
set last  = (select max(yyyymmdd::number) from YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG);

with
hours as (select row_number() over (order by null) - 1 h from table(generator(rowcount=>24))),
days as  (
  select 
    row_number() over (order by null) - 1 as n,
    to_date($first::text, 'YYYYMMDD')::date + n as d,
    to_char(d, 'YYYYMMDD') as yyyymmdd
  from table(generator(rowcount=>($last-$first+1)))
)
select days.yyyymmdd || lpad(hours.h,2,0) as YYYYMMDDHH, nvl2(t.yyyymmddhh,1,0) as HOUR_EXISTS
from days cross join hours
left join YYYYMMDDHH_DATA_AGG t on t.yyyymmddhh = days.yyyymmdd || lpad(hours.h,2,0)
order by 1
;
```

$first and $last can be packed in as sub-queries if you prefer.